# CSS3 Animation doesn't work well in Firefox (transition is not smooth)

Tags: css, firefox, css-animations

I made a background-image slider which works well in Chrome and Edge but not in Firefox.

In Chrome the background images changes to another image and the transition goes smooth (like it should be). But in Firefox there is no visible 'smooth' transition. The background images are changing but the transition is instant.

I already put the vendor prefix in my CSS:

```
-webkit-animation: hero-slider 15s infinite;
-moz-animation: hero-slider 15s infinite;
-ms-animation: hero-slider 15s infinite;
animation: hero-slider 15s infinite;
```

I also defined the four different animations with the prefix:

```
@-webkit-keyframes hero-slider
{}

@-moz-keyframes hero-slider
{}

@-ms-keyframes hero-slider
{}

@keyframes hero-slider
{}
```

I also tried this:

```
-webkit-animation: hero-slider 15s;
-moz-animation: hero-slider 15s;
-ms-animation: hero-slider 15s;
animation: hero-slider 15s;

-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;

-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

- Firefox version: 82.0.3
- Chrome version: 86.0.4240.198
- Edge version: 86.0.622.69

Do you have any suggestions why the transition is not smooth in Firefox?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No need for **any** vendor prefix for years already for the `animation` property

Comment: Please provide a workable demo right here in your question.